# Problem Implementing MLE Estimation in bbmle Package (for R)

Tags: r, estimation

I am trying to verify the MLEs obtained for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\lambda$ for the Logistic-Lomax distribution in the paper entitled [A Study of Logistic-Lomax Distribution](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314211811_A_Study_of_Logistic-Lomax_Distribution_and_Its_Applications) by Zubair et al when using Data Set 1. The paper uses the following code to do this (see Appendix B):

```
library(bbmle)
x <- c(66, 117, 132, 111, 107, 85, 89, 79, 91, 97, 138, 103, 111, 86, 78, 96, 93, 101, 102, 110, 95, 96, 88, 122, 115, 92, 137, 91, 84, 96, 97, 100, 105, 104, 137, 80, 104, 104, 106, 84, 92, 86, 104, 132, 94, 99, 102, 101, 104, 107, 99, 85, 95, 89, 102, 100, 98, 97, 104, 114, 111, 98, 99, 102, 91, 95, 111, 104, 97, 98, 102, 109, 88, 91, 103, 94, 105, 103, 96, 100, 101, 98, 97, 97, 101, 102, 98, 94, 100, 98, 99, 92, 102, 87 , 99, 62, 92, 100, 96, 98) 
n <- length(x)
ll_LLx <- function(alpha, beta, lambda){
n*log(lambda*alpha/beta)-sum(log(1+x/beta))
-(lambda+1)*sum(log(log((1+x/beta)^alpha)))
-2*sum(log(1+(log((1+x/beta)^alpha))^(-lambda)))
}
mle.res <- mle2(ll_LLx, start=list(alpha=alpha, beta=beta, lambda=lambda),
hessian.opt=TRUE)
summary(mle.res)
```

The paper obtains the values $\hat{\alpha} =  0.5302, \hat{\beta} = 17.6331, \hat{\lambda} = 35.6364$ for the MLEs fo this dataset using this code. My question is simply this: how do I implement this code in R without it spitting out an error? This code appears to list the parameters as 'alpha', 'beta' and 'lambda', but does not assign them numerical starting values. So I tried to put reasonable starting values for these parameters before the code as follows:

```
alpha=0.5
beta=17
lambda=35
```

However, this gave the unexpected error:

```
Error in optim(par = c(alpha = 0.5, beta = 17, lambda = 35), fn = function (p)  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

What has happened here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think this post should have been migrated. Migrating it breaks the math notation, and while one of the issues is straightforwardly about coding, the other isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

First

```
> alpha=0.53
> beta=17.6
> lambda=35.6
> ll_fragment<-function(alpha,beta,gamma) -2*sum(log(1+(log((1+x/beta)^alpha))^(-lambda)))
> 
> ll_LLx(alpha,beta,gamma)
[1] -205.132
> ll_fragment(alpha,beta,gamma)
[1] -205.132
```

That is, the printing of the code introduced line breaks, and when you copy the code from the PDF, you end up with a series of three expressions. The value returned by the function is then just the value of the last expression.

Second, if you compare the code to the loglikelihood defined in equation number ... defined in the unnumbered equation before equation 6.1, the equation starts with $n\log\frac{\lambda\alpha}{\beta}$.  The code has
`n*log(lambda*alpha/beta)`.  These look the same, but `mle2` is a *minimiser*, so they should have opposite sign.   The equation for the loglikelihood matches the pdf in equation 2.2, so I assume it's right and the code as given will attempt to minimise the loglikelihood.

If I fix the line breaks and the sign, I get

```
> mle.res <- mle2(ll1a, start=list(alpha=alpha, beta=beta, lambda=lambda),hessian=TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In log(lambda * alpha/beta) : NaNs produced
2: In log(log((1 + x/beta)^alpha)) : NaNs produced
3: In log(lambda * alpha/beta) : NaNs produced
4: In log(log((1 + x/beta)^alpha)) : NaNs produced
5: In log(lambda * alpha/beta) : NaNs produced
6: In log(log((1 + x/beta)^alpha)) : NaNs produced
> summary(mle.res)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = ll1a, start = list(alpha = alpha, beta = beta, 
    lambda = lambda), hessian.opts = TRUE)

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
alpha   0.530499   0.018522  28.641 < 2.2e-16 ***
beta   17.649226   1.357944  12.997 < 2.2e-16 ***
lambda 35.636033   2.260395  15.765 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

-2 log L: 771.2541
```

in good agreement with the paper.

This is why code *in a repository* rather than in a PDF should be required, but even getting code is a big step forward for this sort of paper

Comment: Thank you very much. What would your advice be on choosing sensible starting values? Even the discrepancy in the values used in my question and in your answer leads to differences in the MLEs (although the LL value is the same in each case).

Comment: Any suggestions? @Thomas Lumley

Comment: I think your starting values are sensible.  To get better agreement on the actual MLE, you'd want a stricter tolerance for convergence, with `control=list(reltol=1e-10)`. That won't get you the published values: I got $\alpha=0.5632221, \beta=20.1084476, \lambda=34.2831322$, where the loglikelihood is slightly higher so the published value isn't quite the MLE.  If I were doing inference here I'd also draw $\ell$ contours for pairs of parameters to see how far from elliptical they were and get a better idea of the shape of uncertainty